# Pthread Mutex Segfault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, mutex

I've never worked with pthreads before and am simply trying to familiarize myself with them. As such, I've written the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int count = 0;

void *increment(void *tex);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &increment, &mutex);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &increment, &mutex);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &increment, &mutex);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_join(t3, NULL);
    printf("Value of count is: %d\n", count);
}

void *increment(void *tex) {
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) mutex;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I'm compiling the code with GCC using the proper -pthread flag, yet, for whatever reason, any time that any of the threads reach the mutex locking line, segfault. Upon further investigation with GDB, I've discovered that the mutex pointer appears to be invalid inside of the increment function even though I initialized it in main, passed it in as the argument to pthread_create, and have called join on each thread to ensure that main is still in scope. I'm at a loss for why this is happening, and could use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got:

```
pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) mutex;
```

what you need is:

```
pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) tex;
```

Comment: ... and even there, the cast is completely superfluous in C.

Comment: And there's another typo where `t2` is initialized twice and `t3` never initialized.  Copy/paste can be the source of some irritating bugs.

Comment: Also, note that using `-Wall` warns about `t3` being uninitialized. `-Wall` doesn't warn about the `mutex` self-initialization; it would be nice if it did (and it seems like it would be an easy diagnostic to generate).

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww, that's so dumb. I didn't even know that self initialization was a thing. Also, yeah, I never noticed the t2 being initialized twice because the program always segfaulted before getting to that line. Thanks!